# SQL left outer join - same named fields as rows instead of columns

Tags: sql, union

I have 14 tables that describe a hierarchical XML data structure. One field is a key for the row and another field is a foreign key to its parent. The remaining 60 fields are the same in each table.

I would like to get one large serial list of rows instead of horizontally adding the columns.

For example the following is set up to give me 6 columns. How can I serialize it into 3 columns and more rows?

```
SELECT ICN2.ICNID, ICN2.ICNTITLE, ICN2.PANE, ICN3.ICNID AS ICNID2,
    ICN3.ICNTITLE AS ICNTITLE2, ICN3.PANE AS PANE2
FROM ICN2
LEFT OUTER JOIN ICN3 ON ICN2.ICN2_PKEY = ICN3.ICN2_FKEY
WHERE ICN2.ICNID = N'65587'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an SQL `UNION` to create a single (aliased) result set, then apply the condition:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ICNID, ICNTITLE, PANE
    FROM ICN2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ICNID, ICNTITLE, PANE
    FROM ICN3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ICNID, ICNTITLE, PANE
    FROM ICN4
    ... ) A
WHERE ICNID = N'65587'
```

This is the syntax for mysql and postgres, but the exact syntax may vary depending on which database you are using.

If you need to know *which* table the rows came from, add a constant to each row:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 'ICN2' as SOURCE, ICNID, ICNTITLE, PANE
    FROM ICN2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ICN3', ICNID, ICNTITLE, PANE
    FROM ICN3
    UNION ALL
    ... ) A
WHERE ICNID = N'65587'
```

BTW `UNION ALL` preserves ordering and duplicate rows. Plain `UNION` sorts and removes duplicate rows. Chose which ever suits you best

Comment: Thanks - i am searching how to Apply the Full Union to a nesting of Right Outer Join   SELECT     ICN3.*, ICN2.*
FROM         ICN3  RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      ICN2 ON ICN3.ICN2_FKEY = ICN2.ICN2_PKEY
WHERE     (ICN2.ICNID = N'65587'

Comment: See modified answer that uses just one `WHERE` clause

Comment: I think i was not as specifc in that i had a chained out hiearchy of left join. I was not able to construct a SQL query but i was able to create a recursive loop that would delve in using visual basic.